# Convert Date to DateTime in SQL and Query great than

Tags: sql, datetime, date

I am having an issue with the most simple command in SQL Server Management.  It seems the issue with is in the converting process.  The current column is set to date only but I need to be able to specify the range under date and time.  I would ultimately like to query where datetime is greater than the previous days datetime.

Can anyone lend me a hand on this one?  I am pulling may hair out on the most simple query.

```
Select
  FROM [CustomerTracking].[dbo].[Submission]
  WHERE 
  Date(CONVERT(Datetime, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 102)) 
  is BETWEEN '2012-03-14 12:23:00' AND 'Now'
GO
```

Comment: Which column has the `Date` value in it?

Comment: This was SOOOOO helpful - thank you both for helping save the last of my hair.  I was WAY over thinking the problem at this point.  I am soooo glad its Friday now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [Submission]
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,[DateOnlyColName]) 
    BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2012 12:15:00') AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: This was SOOOOO helpful - thank you both for helping save the last of my hair.  I was WAY over thinking the problem at this point.  I am sooo glad its Friday now.

Comment: If this was the correct solution, you should mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
Select *
From [CustomerTracking].[dbo].[Submission] 
Where Convert(Datetime, [YOUR_DATE_COLUMN], 102) Between '2012-03-14 12:23:00'
AND Getdate()
```